# Executing ExtendScript from AppleScript in InDesign 2020

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to open and execute a JSX script via AppleScript with `do script` command as described in [Adobe InDesign Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_AS.pdf) on [this page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) and elsewhere on the interwebs:

> The `do script` method gives a script a way to execute another script. The script can be a string of valid scripting code or a file on disk.

script.scpt:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
    activate
    set jsx_script to "Macintosh HD:Users:xxx:project:script.jsx"
    set val_1 to "Foo"
    set val_2 to "Bar"
    set my_values to {val_1, val_2}
    do script jsx_script language javascript with arguments my_values
end tell
```

script.jsx:

```
#target "InDesign"

testFunc(arguments);

function testFunc(t) {
    alert('argument one: ' + t[0] + '\r' + 'argument two: ' + t[1]);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I'm getting "Expected end of line, etc. but found “script”." syntax error. Does it mean `do script` is no longer supported? My environment is macOS 10.15.3 and InDesign 2020 (15.0.2). Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved itself with update to macOS 10.15.4.